# Convert string to PowerShell date and time format

Tags: powershell, datetime

I could use some help figuring out the formatting syntax for converting a string to DateTime in PowerShell. I've tried many combinations and continue to get
`Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`

The code I'm trying to use is as follows:

```
$timeinfo = '1/‎3/‎2020 ‏‎9:56 AM'
$template = 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
[DateTime]::ParseExact($timeinfo, $template, $culture)
```

I'm using syntax that I found here: https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/parsing-custom-datetime-formats. Would someone be willing to show me what I'm doing wrong? I'm stuck! Thanks so much!

Comment: Your `$timeinfo` string is filled with hidden Left-to-Right Mark control characters, sanitize the string and it'll work: `$timeinfo = $timeinfo -replace '\p{Cf}'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you so much! That did the trick! Never would have thought about hidden characters.

Answer (score 0):

try this and let the parser do the work:

```
$timeinfo = '04/02/2020 02:00 PM'

[datetime]$timeinfo
```